Error: Unable to resolve module ./http://localhost:8081/index from None of these files exist:* http:/localhost:8081/index(.native|.ios.js|....)
node version: v16.15.1
xcode version: v16.1
macOs: 15.1
Simulator: iPhone 15 pro iOS 17.5
My application was running using
react-native start --reset-cache

on simulator fine but when I try to use my signin methods or register doesn't connect and show me these error
